# The noun-phrase complement as "that-clause"

Tags: clauses

Can I use a noun-phrase complement as "that-clause" ?

For example :

> I am looking forward to that they will visit us.

Comment: This is a good question!  The short answer is **no, you can't use a that-clause here.**  "I am looking forward to" takes a noun phrase, like "visiting Boston", or "a well-deserved rest", but not a that-clause.  Maybe somebody else can explain it a little more fully?

Comment: This may help you [here](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/english-grammar/verbs/verbs-followed-that-clause) and [here](http://www.grammar-quizzes.com/clause5.html)

Answer (score 1):

<sup>OK</sup> {That they will visit us} is cause for happiness.

<sup>OK</sup> I know|hope|suppose|imagine|predict|bet|anticipate|wish|am delighted|etc {that they will visit us}.

But the **to** of **looking forward to** (and similar verbs) cannot be complemented by a that-clause.

<sup>OK</sup> I am accustomed to {the noise}.

<sup>not OK</sup> I am accustomed to {that it is noisy}.

P.S. We would say:

I am accustomed to {*the fact*} {that it is noisy}.

Answer (score 0):

After a verb + preposition can follow only a noun or a gerund, a that-clause can not follow.

But there is a second possibility when you use a verb + preposition, the preposition is dropped, eg

- to agree on/about sth: They managed to agree on a date for the wedding.
- to agree + that-clause: We agreed (that) the proposal was a good one.

http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/agree?q=agree